# Phaser load csv file and display on screen by createLayer function

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi I copied this code from phaser examples and I have this error:

TypeError: map.createLayer is not a function. (In 'map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0)', 'map.createLayer' is undefined)

I have problem with creating layer from ".csv" file

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('tiles', './assets/drawtiles-spaced.png');
    this.load.image('car', './assets/car90.png');
    this.load.tilemapCSV('map', './assets/grid.csv');
}

function create ()
{
    var map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map', tileWidth: 32, tileHeight: 32 });
    var tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles', null, 32, 32, 1, 2);
    var layer = map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);
```

Solution of problem

Comment: you would need to share more code, and maybe your csv file, the code you posted is not the cause of the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well this error indicates, that the variable `map` is `undefined`, but it is strange, that error happens in that specific line of code, and not one line higher.

If `map` is really `undefined` then the code-line

```
var tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles', null, 32, 32, 1, 2);
```

should also throw a similar error. *Are you deleting / destroying the map data in some other part of your programm.*

Comment: No, what I send so its whole my code

Comment: @Wojnys well I tested it with many different ways, the only thing I can still think of, is check the phaser version (if you are uptodate), and if the image and csv-file is in the correct format. (image right size and proportion, and the csv is also in the right format). I downloaded all files from [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/csv-map#) and it works.

Comment: @Wojnys are there any other error messages in the browser console?

Comment: just this: TypeError: map.createLayer is not a function. (In 'map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0)', 'map.createLayer' is undefined)